# Vim, see autoindent state in statusbar

Tags: vim, statusbar, auto-indent

Is it possible to have the statusbar in Vim display wether autoindent is on or not?

I have been googling for it and read the following in the Vim homepage:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27statusline%27
seems like its not possible.

Comment: Beware of the XY problem: ask about your problem, not your solution that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `%{...}` to evaluate a custom expression in the status line

```
set statusline=%{&autoindent?'autoindent':'noautoindent'}
```

I didn't put spaces in the expression but if you want them you can use `\` to escape them like

```
set statusline=%{&autoindent\ ?\ 'autoindent'\ :\ 'noautoindent'}
```

However it might be easier to put it in a function and call the function.